# Spring Form: My not null value becomes null after submitting the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am using

- Hibernate
- Spring
- Apache Tiles
- JSTL

I am putting filled value in my form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
public String createInsuranceType(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    InsuranceType insuranceType = new InsuranceType();
    InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany = insuranceCompanyService
            .getInsuranceCompanyById(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")));
    insuranceType.setInsuranceCompany(insuranceCompany);
    model.addAttribute("insuranceType", insuranceType);
    System.out.println(insuranceType);
    return "insurancetype-create";
}
```

And this is my console output

```
InsuranceType [id=0, type=null, insuranceCompany=InsuranceCompany [id=1, fullName=full, shortName=short]]
```

And in my form in jsp file I would like to fill only type value, but i want my insuranceCompany stay like it is. My form:

```
<sf:form method="post"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insurancetype/create"
    commandName="insuranceType" id="insuranceTypeForm" class="col s12">
    <sf:hidden path="id" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <sf:input path="type" id="type" type="text" class="validate" />
            <label for="type">Insurance Type</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${insuranceType.id < 1}">
                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('insuranceTypeForm').submit()"
                        class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i
                        class="material-icons right">save</i>Zapisz</a>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('insuranceTypeForm').submit()"
                        class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i
                        class="material-icons right">edit</i>Edytuj</a>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </div>
    </div>
</sf:form>
```

And after submit my output looks like this:

```
InsuranceType [id=0, type=test value, insuranceCompany=null]
```

My POST controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insuranceTypeCreated(@ModelAttribute("insuranceType") InsuranceType insuranceType,
        @RequestParam("id") long id) {
    System.out.println(insuranceType);
    insuranceTypeService.insertOrUpdateInsuranceType(insuranceType);
    if (id < 1)
        return "redirect:/insurancecompany/list";
    else
        return "redirect:/insurancetype/list";
}
```

I tried something like

```
<sf:hidden path="insuranceCompany" />
```

But it returns error

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `modelAttribute="insuranceType"` in your `sf:form` tag.

Comment: It doesn't work, but thank you a lot for response :)